# DOORS 9 cannot handle network connection switch

Tags: ibm-doors

We are running IBM Rational DOORS 9.3. When I dock or undock my laptop with an open network connection, and the connection switches between Wi-Fi and Ethernet, DOORS crashes. Is this normal? Do others have this problem and have you come up with any workarounds?

I have not found anything on the IBM DOORS support site, and everyone else here has just learned to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Run it over Citrix and not on your local machine. This is much faster client performance (as long as your Windows/Citrix is on the same LAN as the DOORS Server), can handle network connection breaks (if you configure Citrix correctly it will reconnect your session automatically) and is easier to administer.